# Is it possible to create a shortcode that will query a post based on taxonomies?

Tags: custom-post-types, custom-taxonomy, wp-query, query, shortcode

I am working on a site that will be listing a few hundred products and we wanted to be able to quickly/easily show specific products on a page based on taxonomies. I have been doing some research and thought I was on the right track.

First, I found [this article on digwp.com](http://digwp.com/2010/01/custom-query-shortcode/) which I thought was going to work great. I can not get it to pull the posts based on taxonomy though - just post_type. The Post Type is "Used Items" and I created a taxonomy named Color where one of the slugs was Red.

```
[loop the_query="post_type=used-items&color=red&ord=ASC"]
```

I also [found this plugin](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/dzs-custom-wp-query-shortcode/) for doing a query by shortcode, but same situation with it not pulling by taxonomy.

**My question**
Does anyone know what I can do to pull posts based on post type/taxonomies (would be using multiple each query) directly from a WordPress page. We want to be able to quickly query products without having to program the query into a page template for each possible option.

Answer (score 4):

here is a simple shortcode that can handle taxonomies, post types and any other parameter that WP_Query takes:

```
add_shortcode('posts','posts_shortcode_handler');
function posts_shortcode_handler($atts, $content){
    extract(shortcode_atts(array(
        'posts_per_page' => '5',
    ), $atts));

    global $post;
    $temp = $post;

    $posts = new WP_Query($atts);
    $retVal = '';
    if ($posts->have_posts()){
        while ($posts->have_posts()){
            $posts->the_post();

            // these arguments will be available from inside $content
            $parameters = array(
                'PERMALINK' => get_permalink(),
                'TITLE' => get_the_title(),
                'CONTENT' => get_the_content(),
                'CATEGORIES' => get_the_category_list(', '),
                'THUMBNAIL' => get_the_post_thumbnail()
            );

            $finds = $replaces = array();
            foreach($parameters as $find => $replace){
                $finds[] = '{'.$find.'}';
                $replaces[] = $replace;
            }
            $retVal .= str_replace($finds, $replaces, $content);

        }
    }
    wp_reset_query();
    $post = $temp;
    return $retVal;
}
```

usage:

```
[posts post_type="page" posts_per_page=5 taxonomy_name="taxonomy_term"]
    <h5><a href="{PERMALINK}">{TITLE}</a></h5>
    <div>{THUMBNAIL} <br />{CONTENT}</div>
[/posts]
```

replace page with your post type name, taxonomy_name with your taxonomy name and taxonomy_term with the taxonomy term

Comment: Looks great so far. Two questions that hopefully you can help with. 1). How would I search if I wanted to pull results that contained two taxonomy terms from the same taxonomy name. So only if Red and Blue were selected for the term Color, but it has to be both colors. Make sense? 2). Any way of putting the output code into the function so I only need to put the shortcode in and it displays the output code I want each time (title, link, thumbnail).?  Thanks for such a quick response!

Comment: 1) you would need to edit the function to handle multiple taxonomy terms using `tax_query` and as for the template you can hard-code it in the function and you will never have to enter it again :)

Comment: Would you be able to assist me with this? I am not sure where to edit the function for the output. I am looking to have it out the title, thumbnail and have both link to the page. I am also not sure how to setup the 'tax_query'. If you can help me I would really appreciate it, this stuff always gives me trouble :)

Comment: Is this still the best way? Also, how would you adjust the order of the output?

Comment: Also, this seems to add blank <p></p> tags before and after each item.